# How to only list audio devices using FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, input-devices, enumerate-devices, audio-device

I am doing an audio recording project using FFmpeg 5.0.1. To list all the available audio input devices for the user to select and use, I used the function `avdevice_list_input_sources()`. My code goes like this:

```
avdevice_list_input_sources(av_find_input_format("dshow"), NULL, NULL, &device_list);
```

Where `device_list` is declared as

```
AVDeviceInfoList* device_list;
```

But this way, all the input devices supported, including audio *and* video, are listed. This could compromise the program's stability, for the user could select a video device listed and cause the program to crash. So I need to find a way to *only* list audio input devices or delete the video devices from `device_list`. But so far, I have not found a feasible away.

Does anyone know how to do so?